# Azure Event Hub : What is a 'Field Gateway'?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Scott Guthrie's [announcement of Azure Event Hubs](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/azure-announcing-new-real-time-data-streaming-and-data-factory-services) shows the below diagram which includes something called a 'field gateway'.

[image]

I've not been able to find a definition of what this concept means. I'm hoping it's a device-side SDK for sending events to Azure Event Hubs. Is it?

Comment: There is an SDK, here's the walkthrough I used to set up Device-to-Cloud message ingest and processing: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-process-d2c/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A fields gateway is simply an aggregation point for a range of in-place sensors. Many low powered / basic devices do not have enough capacity to run secured HTTP sessions so in these cases there will typically be a gateway to which these devices send their data. The gateway can aggregate / store and then forward the data securely onto Azure Event Hubs.

To answer your question: it isn't a device-side SDK.